# Save button never greys out when using Office365 apps

Tags: windows-10, office365

For the past few years, I have been using Office 365 (Word, Excel, etc) apps on Windows 10. One thing that has bother me since then is the behaviour of the Save button. On previous version, after clicking it, it became greyed out to indicate that the file has been saved. And became active again if there were changes made. However with Office 365, the button remains active even after saving a file. It never greys out.

I changed its position from above to below the ribbon thinking that it will acts as it did with previous versions; but it did not. These 2 images show the button still activated after I save a file using Word.

**Save button above the ribbon**                          **Save button below the ribbon**
[image: Save button above ribbon]        [image: Save button below the ribbon]

Is this a change implemented with Office 365, Office 2016 and above versions? Is there a settings that will allow it to work as previous versions of Office did?

Comment: I have Office 365 here. The Title bar shows AutoSave (off here) and the Save button as you show in your first screen line. When you save, there is no indication in the title bar that the file has been saved. Some of us save a document, then might make another change and save again. So this works as expected and if I make a mistake and close the app, it will tell me the file has not been saved if that is the case.

Comment: @John If you save the save, then the expected behaviour will be for the button to not be active (grey out), and become active when/after you have changes (as it was with Office 2010, 2013, 2007, etc).

Comment: The button does not grey out after save on the newest versions of Office. I have double checked this behavior on a couple of properly running machines. You would have to submit a feature request to Microsoft